# Need help fixing code to swap camera positions in Unity3D with C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm revising a code so that a camera will cycle through 3 different locations on a ship. The problem I've come across with this code is that it will only go to a 2nd location & stays there. It needs to cycle through but doesn't.

This is the code I'm working with:

```
    public void CycleCameraView (Vector3 inputValue, int customPlayerInputEventType)
    {
        // Cycle the current camera view index to the next view.
        currentCameraViewIndex = (currentCameraViewIndex + 1) % 3;

        SetCurrentView(currentCameraViewIndex);
    }

    public int GetCurrentCameraViewIndex ()
    {
        return currentCameraViewIndex;
    }

    public int GetNextCameraViewIndex ()
    {
        return (currentCameraViewIndex + 1) % 3;
    }

    public void SetCurrentView(int viewIndex)
    {
        if (viewIndex >= 0 && viewIndex < 3 && shipCameraModule != null)
        {
            currentCameraViewIndex = viewIndex;

            if (currentCameraViewIndex == 0)
            {
                // Camera view 1
                // Set the camera parameters to match camera view 1
                
            }
            else if (currentCameraViewIndex == 1)
            {
                // Camera view 2
                // Set the camera parameters to match camera view 2
         
                
            }
            else
            {
                // Camera view 3
                // Set the camera parameters to match camera view 3
                
            }
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: Which of those method/s are you calling when you try to change the camera view? Also is it possible the issue is inside one of the omitted `// Set the camera parameters to match camera view x` parts?

Comment: SetCurrentView() is what's invoked. The parameters inside the "set camera parameters" doesn't have anything that'd cause a problem.

Answer (score 1):

First, you are repeating your code here which is obviously not a good practice.

```
(currentCameraViewIndex + 1) % 3;
```

Call the GetNextCameraViewIndex and bring the above logic there.

```
 public void CycleCameraView (Vector3 inputValue, int customPlayerInputEventType)
    {
        // Cycle the current camera view index to the next view.
        currentCameraViewIndex = GetNextCameraViewIndex; 
        SetCurrentView(currentCameraViewIndex);
    }



public int GetNextCameraViewIndex ()
    {
        return (currentCameraViewIndex + 1) % 3; // Please correct if required, I'm not on a dev machine.
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Naveed, how do I go about fixing this? When I tried to debug this code, I did a print to see which view is active, it was showing all 3 views from SetCurrentView()

Comment: You need to debug the code when calling the GetNextCameraViewIndex, `if statements` and the `parameters they send`.

Comment: I've made the edits, please note that I'm not on a dev machine and this is untested code. Let me know if it didn't work, I'll try to simulate it for you.

Comment: Thanks for the hint...didn't get it to work. I'm gonna try a little bit more. If I don't get it working, I'll contact the dev that made this asset (it's an extra, I don't think it was meant for production).

Answer (score -2):

I think we need more stuff if you want us to be able to help you mate. Also, you shouyld definitly use a switch in your SetCurrentView(int viewIndex)

Comment: This is not an answer to the question posted

Comment: Please make sure to be specific about what is required, also this should be a comment not an answer (but I understand you are new, so prolly cannot leave comments)

Comment: Yeah the inability to leave comments can make it harder for new users to help people and thereby earn enough rep to leave comments.